# How to use loaded data to add a new value in an ItemLoader?

Tags: python, scrapy

I have started a scraping project, and I have a small problem with `ItemLoader`.

Suppose I have some `ItemLoader` in a scraper:

```
l = ScraperProductLoader(item=ScraperProduct(), selector=node)
l.add_xpath('sku', 'id/text()')
```

I would like to add a URL to the item loader based on the `sku` I have provided:

```
l.add_value('url', '?????')
```

...However, based on [the documentation](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html), I don't see a clear way to do this.

Options I have considered:

- Input processor: Add a string, and pass the `sku` as the context somehow
- Handle separately: Create the URL without using the item loader

How can I use loaded data to add a new value in an `ItemLoader`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`get_output_value()`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#scrapy.contrib.loader.ItemLoader.get_output_value) method:

> get_output_value(field_name)
>
> Return the collected values parsed using
>   the output processor, for the given field. This method doesn’t
>   populate or modify the item at all.

```
l.add_value('url', 'http://domain.com/' + l.get_output_value('scu'))
```

Comment: Not sure how I missed that. Thanks :)